# Are all swarming missions in xcom long war terror missions?

Tags: xcom-long-war

When I see a mission marked as swarming in xcom long war, I usually think I have to save civilians and chrysallids are there. But once in a while I find that is not the case and there are no civilians to save and so the grenade laden engineer and rocketeer I bought is overkill for this mission. How do I figure out which ones are the real terror missions?

Answer (score 1):

Terror missions should be marked as "Terror attack in x" on your Geoscape.  They additionally have an icon on the Geoscape that looks like a few skyscrapers on fire, compared to other missions which have different icons.